# Create Portable JDBC Connection Pool in Glassfish

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, connection-pooling

I'm trying to deploy my project to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, using Docker with preconfigured Glassfish.

Since the project uses JPA, and EJB to create a transactional persistence unit; I create a database connection pool in the Glassfish admin console, then supply the JNDI string to `persistence.xml`.

All good in my local machine, Amazon won't allow you to use the admin console. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351833/how-to-configure-a-glassfish-instance-running-on-aws-elasticbeanstalk-docker) post, which discusses generally how to configure Glassfish with `asadmin`, but I've found it very hard to follow and sounds very invasive.

Is there a one-size-fits-all solution to create a database connection pool that is automatically allocated on any server I deploy my application to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Although this is unfortunately under-documented.

You can create an *application scoped* connection pool, that Glassfish creates on the fly, when you depoly your war file to it. It will destroy it when undeployed. Though, it is only available to **this** application on the server.

Here's what you should do. Create a file named `glassfish-resources.xml` like this (for MySql):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" name="MySQLPool" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
      <property name="user" value="someUser"></property>
      <property name="password" value="aPassword"></property>
      <property name="databaseName" value="aDatabase"></property>
      <property name="serverName" value="some.string.you got.from.amazon.rds.amazonaws.com"></property>
      <property name="portNumber" value="3306"></property>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource pool-name="MySQLPool" jndi-name="jdbc/MySQLPool"></jdbc-resource>
</resources>
```

And drop it into your `WEB-INF` directory. You should also place the database connection dependency jar in the `lib` directory.

Now since this isn't a global JNDI reference, as it is only available to this application, you should access it in `persistence.xml` with `java:app` prefix, like this:

```
<jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/MySQLPool</jta-data-source>
```